# Auditd Error : arch elf mapping not found

Tags: audit

I have to add rules in auditd.
It seems to work for recording command (option -w) but not for option -a where arch must be specified.

For example :

```
$> auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S adjtimex -S settimeofday -S clock_settime -k timechange 
arch elf mapping not found
    
$> uname -m
aarch64
```

The kernel is compiled with

```
CONFIG_AUDIT=y
CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_AUDITSYSCALL=y
```

Have you got an idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to recompile auditd with the good argument, espicially --with-arm64 during the configure phase.